# SQL - combination of MIN and COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is in Oracle database. Say I have the following table A:

```
column1 column2
id1       a
id2       a 
id3       a
id4       b
id5       b
id6       c
```

So what I want the sql does is:
First count there's three As and two bs and one c, then based on the counts return me the smallest number of these counts, in this case is 1 (because we only have one c)

Can this be achieved somehow by using the combination of MIN and COUNT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(Count) as MinVal
FROM
(SELECT column2,COUNT(column2) as Count
FROM TableA
GROUP BY column2) T
```

**Explanation:**

Inner query select the counts of `column2` for each value of `column2` in the table. Then with the outer query, the minimum count is selected.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can do this directly; count per group and use MIN on the results to get back one row with the desired value.

```
select min(count(*))
from tablea
group by column1;
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: This is not valid in other dbms, but in Oracle yes. You can do the aggregation by group and then another aggregation on those results as shown above without a subquery (though I find a subquery usually better readable).

Comment: . . This must be something new in Oracle 11g.  I tested it on an Oracle 10 database and got the expected error.  But, it does work on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: It also works on my Oracle 10g Enterprise 10.2.0.4.0. So it can as well be a difference between Standard and Enterprise Edition. (Which I would consider strange though.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(cnt)
FROM   (SELECT   COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM     my_table
        GROUP BY column2)
```

**EDIT:**
As  ElmoVanKielmo noted, it's somewhat pointless to offer a solution without explaining it.
The inner query groups the data by `column2` values, and return the number of rows for each one. The outer query treats these as just a bunch of numbers, and returns the minimal value among them.

Comment: REVIEW: Some description for this solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12, you can do this without a subquery:

```
select count(*) as cnt
from table t
group by cnt
order by cnt asc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

For those familiar with MySQL or Postgres, `fetch first 1 row only` is equivalent to `limit`, and allows you to limit the number of output rows without using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT Column2, COUNT(Column1)
FROM TableA
GROUP BY Column2
ORDER BY COUNT(Column1))
WHERE Rownum = 1
```